# Worry about cube size output?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube

I am learning about cubes for the first time, reading a thick red book. The team have a concern:

When creating a SSAS cube, should we be worried about the potential max size output from cube query results? In other words; Given that the users are able to combine several measures, is it so that the resulting database query might yield several GB of data? (Our db is about 10 GB)

Further;
What actions can be undertaken to ensure no single user can hijack the db in this way and ensure that smooth service continues to all users?

Our existing cube solution is based on Mondrian with a JPivot web front. This exhibits the huge output problem. Our new cubes will use SSAS 2008, still to decide on web front.

(Searching for a similar question failed at StackOverflow)

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to consider is whether you'll configure the cube to use ROLAP, MOLAP or HOLAP storage mode.

MOLAP will retrieve data from your data sources and permanently store them in files that will be used by the cube.  This will help query speed considerably, depending on how efficient your source tables return data.  ROLAP does not retrieve any data from the source tables.  Everytime you query the cube, it will access the source to obtain the results.  HOLAP solutions are somewhere between the two.

Regarding the concern for size, will you need to display aggregated totals for all of the columns from the database table?  If you limit the number of measures and dimensions available through the cube, that will decrease the size of the output files.

Comment: I don't know yet if we need to aggregate totals. Possibly most of the database will be accessible through the cube. I guess MOLAP would be choosen, although not sure of the size increment that would give.

Comment: Do you suggest we make many smaller cubes with lesser measures and dimensions. rather than one big with everything in it?

Comment: If you have the Enterprise version, you can define multiple partitions and split the data across these partitions.  That would provide you the same benefits that you might enjoy by splitting data into smaller cubes without the headaches of dealing with multiple cubes.